# Most future-proof way to embed an iframe in an OpenERP view?

Tags: odoo

I wish to customize the partner view form to contain an additional tab (next to History). When clicking on this tab, I wish to show an embedded iframe, where the content is sourced from a different system.

What is the best way to go about this in OpenERP 7.0, such that it doesn't create problems when OpenERP is upgraded?

Thanks.